# Use established PDO connection with Doctrine Master/Slave connection

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm adopting Doctrine in a pre-existing software and would like to have Doctrine share the same PDO connections as the legacy code.

I'm aware you can tell Doctrine use use an established connection like so:

```php
$em = EntityManager::create(['pdo' => $pdo], $ormConfiguration);
```

I have been unable to discover the right combination for master/slave connection.  This is what I expected to work:

```php
$em = EntityManager::create(
    [
        'wrapperClass' => \Doctrine\DBAL\Connections\MasterSlaveConnection::class,
        'master' => ['pdo' => $pdoMaster],
        'slaves' => [
            ['pdo' => $pdoSlave]
        ]
    ],
    $ormConfiguration
);
```

This generates the following error:

> Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException' with message 'The options 'driver' or 'driverClass' are mandatory if no PDO instance is given to DriverManager::getConnection().'.

Reading through the code, it looks like using established connections with Doctrine using Master/Slave is not supported. But I am not sure.  Most docs don't go into details about using established connections.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create connection using `DriverManager::getConnection` and use connection in creating entity manager.

Here an example I found:
https://gist.github.com/ricfrank/d6f6317a1a1434cdc364

```
$conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection(array(
        'wrapperClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Connections\MasterSlaveConnection',
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'keepSlave' => true,
        'master' => array(
            'user'     => 'ideato',
            'password' => 'ideato',
            'dbname'   => 'db_ideato'
        ),
        'slaves' => array(
            array(
                'user' => 'ideato',
                'password' => 'ideato',
                'dbname' => 'db_ideato_slave'
            )
        )
    )
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

Comment: This would create a new DB connection for Doctrine master/slave, but the question was how to use an already established PDO instance.

Comment: In link I provided there is an example of using connection and switching between master/slave

`$masterSlaveConn = $entityManager->getConnection();
$masterSlaveConn->getWrappedConnection();
$masterSlaveConn->connect('slave');`